# Is there a simple C++/.NET game with scripting?

Tags: scripting

I would like to play around with games that use scripting to see how much easier it makes development. What --simple-- C++ or .NET game may i download and play with using a scripting language. I dont really care which scripting language it is.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of games use scripting which allows for not only modding but the creation of completely different games.

Your welcome to purchase [Puzzle Quest 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/47540/) (or any Infinite Interactive game) and see just how easy it is to script with [Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html). Pretty much everything you can do is already in there in the existing scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's not directly what you were asking for, there already is a question regarding games that utilize scripting. Some of them might be options for you as well, notably [LÖVE](http://love2d.org/) (Engine)

[Game engine with good Lua entity creation/management](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4922/game-engine-with-good-lua-entity-creation-management)